# Serial Port Close in scene_update_post

Tags: python

it's me again. :-)

I am able to attach and remove a handler to scene_update_post and do my stuff (sending the scene to a DAC and then to an oszilloscope).

However one thing is bugging me: I can't close the serial port when the handler is removed. It seems that bpy.app.handlers.scene_update_post.clear() does not call any **del** or such functions, so the handler gets removed but the serial port stays open, which forces me to restart Blender. Also I am not using @Persistant so loading a scene will remove the handler but also not closing the serial port.

I guess I missed something or is there a not so obvious way of doing this.

Here is my code, comments on it are apreciated, help for the problem is wanted ;-)

```
# Blender2v scope/vectrex output. 
# Kamera (Name "Camera") muss in Szene existieren (hier auf Layer 11)
# Nur im Object Mode und für Meshes(also nicht während TAB/EditMode)
# Nur Objekte mit Flächen!
# Testobjekte auf Layer 6
# 2016 c.wartmann@gmx.net

import time
import sys
import serial

import bpy
import bpy_extras

from mathutils import Vector,Matrix
import math

# For debugging avoid the handler as it will not be possible to auto close serial?
HAND = True      # adding a handler
HAND = False     # manually run the script

class SerHandle(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.sock=None
        self.sock = serial.Serial('COM10', 9600,timeout=5)
        self.scene = bpy.context.scene
        self.cam = bpy.data.objects.get("Camera")
        if self.cam == None:
            print("No Camera")
            self.sock.close()
            exit

    def __del__(self):
        # why is it not called automatically?
        print("Closing Serial!!!!!")
        self.sock.close()

    '''
     forked from https://bitbucket.org/marcusva/py-sdl2 (which has public-domain license)
     The MIT License (MIT)
     Copyright (c) 2014 Michael Hirsch
     reference: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohen%E2%80%93Sutherland_algorithm
     * I have corrected errors in the cohensutherland code and compared cohensutherland with Matlab polyxpoly() results.
     * The best way to Numba JIT this would probably be in the function calling this, to include the loop itself
       inside the jit decoration.
    '''
    #@jit
    def cohensutherland(self, xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax, x1, y1, x2, y2):
        """Clips a line to a rectangular area.
        This implements the Cohen-Sutherland line clipping algorithm.  xmin,
        ymax, xmax and ymin denote the clipping area, into which the line
        defined by x1, y1 (start point) and x2, y2 (end point) will be
        clipped.
        If the line does not intersect with the rectangular clipping area,
        four None values will be returned as tuple. Otherwise a tuple of the
        clipped line points will be returned in the form (cx1, cy1, cx2, cy2).
        """
        INSIDE,LEFT, RIGHT, LOWER, UPPER = 0,1, 2, 4, 8

        def _getclip(xa, ya):
            p = INSIDE  #default is inside

            # consider x
            if xa < xmin:
                p |= LEFT
            elif xa > xmax:
                p |= RIGHT

            # consider y
            if ya < ymin:
                p |= LOWER # bitwise OR
            elif ya > ymax:
                p |= UPPER #bitwise OR
            return p

    # check for trivially outside lines
        k1 = _getclip(x1, y1)
        k2 = _getclip(x2, y2)

    #%% examine non-trivially outside points
        #bitwise OR |
        while (k1 | k2) != 0: # if both points are inside box (0000) , ACCEPT trivial whole line in box

            # if line trivially outside window, REJECT
            if (k1 & k2) != 0: #bitwise AND &
                 return None, None, None, None

            #non-trivial case, at least one point outside window
            # this is not a bitwise or, it's the word "or"
            opt = k1 or k2 # take first non-zero point, short circuit logic
            if opt & UPPER:
                x = x1 + (x2 - x1) * (ymax - y1) / (y2 - y1)
                y = ymax
            elif opt & LOWER:
                x = x1 + (x2 - x1) * (ymin - y1) / (y2 - y1)
                y = ymin
            elif opt & RIGHT:
                y = y1 + (y2 - y1) * (xmax - x1) / (x2 - x1)
                x = xmax
            elif opt & LEFT:
                y = y1 + (y2 - y1) * (xmin - x1) / (x2 - x1)
                x = xmin
            else:
                raise RuntimeError('Undefined clipping state')
            if opt == k1:
                x1, y1 = x, y
                k1 = _getclip(x1, y1)
            elif opt == k2:
                x2, y2 = x, y
                k2 = _getclip(x2, y2)
        return x1, y1, x2, y2

    def send2v(self):
        vbytes = bytearray(4)
        render_scale = self.scene.render.resolution_percentage / 100
        render_size = (int(self.scene.render.resolution_x * render_scale),int(self.scene.render.resolution_y * render_scale))
        up = self.cam.matrix_world.to_quaternion() * Vector((0.0, 1.0, 0.0))
        cam_direction = self.cam.matrix_world.to_quaternion() * Vector((0.0, 0.0, -1.0))

        for ob in bpy.context.visible_objects:
            if (ob.type in ['MESH']):
                me = ob.data
                wx = ob.location.x
                wy = ob.location.y
                mat = ob.matrix_world
                verts = ob.data.vertices
                edges = me.edges
                for ed in edges:
                    v0_2d = bpy_extras.object_utils.world_to_camera_view(
                                    self.scene, self.cam, mat*verts[ed.vertices[0]].co)
                    v1_2d = bpy_extras.object_utils.world_to_camera_view(
                                    self.scene, self.cam, mat*verts[ed.vertices[1]].co)
                    x0=(v0_2d.x * render_size[0]) 
                    y0=(v0_2d.y * render_size[1]) 
                    x1=(v1_2d.x * render_size[0]) 
                    y1=(v1_2d.y * render_size[1])
                    x0,y0,x1,y1=self.cohensutherland(0,0,render_size[0]-1,
                                                         render_size[1]-1,x0,y0,x1,y1)
                    if (x0!=None):
                        v  = (1) << 30 | (0 & 63) << 24 | (round(x0) & 4095) << 12 | (round(y0) & 4095) << 0
                        vbytes.append((v >> 24) & 0xFF)
                        vbytes.append((v >> 16) & 0xFF)
                        vbytes.append((v >>  8) & 0xFF)
                        vbytes.append((v >>  0) & 0xFF)
                        v  = (1) << 30 | (1 & 63) << 24 | (round(x1) & 4095) << 12 | (round(y1) & 4095) << 0
                        vbytes.append((v >> 24) & 0xFF)
                        vbytes.append((v >> 16) & 0xFF)
                        vbytes.append((v >>  8) & 0xFF)
                        vbytes.append((v >>  0) & 0xFF)


        vbytes.append(1)
        vbytes.append(1)
        vbytes.append(1)
        vbytes.append(1)
        if (self.sock!=None):
            self.sock.write(vbytes)
#        print(vbytes)
#        time.sleep(0.1)


print("-------------------------------")

class update_it(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.handle=SerHandle()
        self.handle.send2v()

    def __del__(self):
        bpy.app.handlers.scene_update_post.clear()
        del self.handle
    def __clear__(self):
        bpy.app.handlers.scene_update_post.clear()
        del self.handle

    def scene_update(self,object):
            objects = bpy.data.objects
            if objects.is_updated:
                #print("update")
                self.handle.send2v()

HAND = True      # adding a handler DEBUG


# not called automatically? (when removing handler)
if (not HAND):
    handle=SerHandle()
    handle.send2v()
    del handle
else:
# Append Handler
    upd=update_it()
    bpy.app.handlers.scene_update_post.append(upd.scene_update)




# Remove Handler, does not remove Comport? .remove does not work at all?
#bpy.app.handlers.scene_update_post.clear()
```